# Type script in mongo createModel

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript

```
 async createModel(models: Collection): Promise<void> {
        for (const model of **models**) { // ts warn in this
            await this.createCollection<typeof model>(
                models['collectionName'],
                {
                    validator: {
                        $jsonSchema: model['schema'],
                    },
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

I created class Store to work with mongo, and I have this error
-> TS2488: Type 'Collection ' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

Comment: what is `Collection`?

Comment: it's interface from mongo http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html

Comment: Can you add your imports?

Comment: yap  -> import { MongoClient, Db, MongoClientOptions, Collection } from 'mongodb'